# Louts notes java agent emails are struck in outbox

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am running Java agent on Louts notes generic id's. I am returning some emails based on validation. Those emails are struck on local lotus notes client outbox.
It was working from long time almost 1 and half years. Its stopped working now.
We haven't changed any code.
Only change I know one of the developer opened louts notes client on that batch processing system and opened couple of inbox fog giving access to users.
We are using Louts notes 9.

my code look like.

```
NotesThread.sinitThread();
Session session = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess();
Registration reg = session.createRegistration();

reg.switchToID(inboxUserId(),inboxPassword());
DbDirectory dbdir=session.getDbDirectory(nsfFile);

DataBase db = session.getDatabase(host, nsfFile);
View inboxView = db.getView("Inbox");
Document doc = vw.getFirstDocument();

if(!isValidEmailDoc(doc){
    Document returnDoc = doc.createReplyMessage(true);
    returnDoc.copyAllItems(doc, true);
    returnDoc.send(doc.getItemValue("From"));
}else{
.....
}
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: The first thing I look at in that kind of situation is the location in use and what the settings are on that location document.  The developer may have inadvertently (or otherwise) switched locations when opening the dbs for the other users.

Comment: I agree. For a client that is running an agent to send emails, I would expect the location document to have the Mail File Location setting "On server", and it sounds like it was changed to "Local".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fingered out the issue. This issue we never opened Louts notes Client on that system. Louts notes client should not configured to any generic emails. Agent should use Notes installation for API calls.

When Louts notes client was opened on that system Developer configured to one generic inbox. When agent returning emails out box is not configured to send emails which is not owner of that inbox. So those return emails are struck on outbox.

Fix is I have uninstalled the client and removed all folders and installed client again. Agent able to send emails once. its reinstalled.